# Able to send values using setValue() in Android OS 6.0 but not working in OS 8.0 and 9.0 while using appium

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

Hi i am using appium(using java) for entering otp value in otp screen

I am using `setValue()` for entering values in otp fields
I am able to execute this in android os 6.0 and 6.1.0 but while executing this in os versions such as 8.0 and 9.0 after entering first otp value an exception occurs:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException:
>   io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException:
>   Cannot set the element to '2'. Did you interact with the correct
>   element?

This is the code block that is used by me

```
((MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(EditProfilePage.getPinEntry1()))).setValue(pin1);
((MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(EditProfilePage.getPinEntry2()))).setValue(pin2);
((MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(EditProfilePage.getPinEntry3()))).setValue(pin3);
((MobileElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(EditProfilePage.getPinEntry4()))).setValue(pin4);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Error Trace-

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Cannot set the element to '8'. Did you interact with the correct element?
at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.SendKeysToElement.safeHandle(SendKeysToElement.java:95)
at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:36)
at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:250)
at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:241)
at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:44)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Capabilities are

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 90000);
capabilities.setCapability("disableWindowAnimation", true);
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions","true");
```

Comment: Which version of appium server are you using? Can you try removing **automationName** > **uiautomator2** from **desiredcapabilities** and try to run test?

Comment: I am using Appium Version 1.10.0

Comment: This is not related to your original question, but you might want to consider lowering your parameter for newCommandTimeout.  It's supposed to be seconds, not milliseconds.  It's not the cause of your problem, but just a friendly heads-up.

Comment: Also, from what I've researched, setValue is apparently only valid for IOS, not Android.  You may need to revert to .clear() and .sendKeys() but other research shows that sendKeys AND setValue both are buggy.